# Django query and comparing [X] or [X,Y] values of a field to [X,Y,Z, W, etc.]

Tags: django, filter

I am trying to obtain certain records using this query:

```
model.objects.all().filter(category__in=context['cat'])
```

`context['cat']` is a list of categories [X, Y, Z, W...]. But a record may be associated with several of them:

[X] or [X,Y] or [X, Y, Z] or [X, Z]

But, this query only gives back records which have 1 category, e.g: [X], or [Y], but not [X,Y].

I have this:

```
[item for item in model.objects.all() if any(category in item.category for category in context['cat'])]
```

This works correctly and gives back the records I want, as I compare every single category with the rest, but the executing time is way too long.

Is there a way to use `.filter()` and something instead of a `for` for this case?

**EDIT:** I did tried using `Q` objects, but they give no results back:

```
paper_list = model.objects.filter(Q(category__in=context['cat']), Q(category__in=context['cat']))
```

Comment: We need more details. What is the `category` field?

Comment: It's a field on a model which goes as:  category = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200). This category field on the records can have values of X or Y, or sometime X,Y. The problem exists with records which have the value X,Y in the category field which are not given after using the first query posted

Comment: Hmm, that seems like the wrong structure. Why not use a proper relational structure, with a foreign key from a separate table which stores the categories?

Comment: I guess I get lost on that part now. I'm fairly new to databases. In case that is of any help the structure of the model is... :    class model(models.Model): 
 date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 author = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 category = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200)

Comment: See the tutorial, which links multiple Choices to one Question.

Comment: ruddra posted an answer. I'll check the link to multiple Choices to one Question anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman is right. You should probably use [ManytoMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field here.

But this hacky solution may be helpful here:

Suppose your `context['cat']` is a list which is `['X', 'Y']`, so what we can do is like this:

```
all_items = model.objects.none()
For catg in context['cat']:
    items = model.objects.filter(category__icontains = catg)
    all_items= all_items | items

# use all_items
```

Comment: That did solve the problem. I will also check the link. Thanks!